# Composition in function fields

Tags: fields, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers, p-adic

Let $k=\mathbb F_q\left(\!\left(\frac1T\right)\!\right)$. One has the map: $\circ:k\times\{v\in k\mid\deg(v)>0\}\to k$ defined by $f\circ g=\sum_{n\ge-m}a_ng^{-n}$ where $f=\sum_{n\ge-m}a_n\frac1{T^n}$ ($m\in\mathbb N_0$, $a_n\in\mathbb F_q$).
Denote by $\Omega$ a completion of $\overline k$ for the valuation $-\deg$. Can one extend $\circ$ continuously to $\Omega\times \{v\in\Omega\mid\deg(v)>0\}$?